Cusp-singularity in metric on the plane
Consider polar coordinates $r,\theta$ with $0 \leq r, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ on the 2D plane. The flat metric is given by $$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}r^2 + a(r)^2 \mathrm{d} \theta^2$$ with $$a(r) = r \,.$$ Now consider more general functions $a(r)$. What are the conditions on $a(r)$ (or $a(r)^2$) so that this metric is regular in a neighborhood of $r = 0$?
Unfortunately, I do not know precisely what I mean by "regular" -- this is part of the question: what is a standard/reasonable option for this definition? Maybe a good choice is the condition that no curvature invariants $R, R_{\mu \nu} R^{\mu \nu}, \nabla_\mu R_{\alpha \beta} \nabla^\mu R^{\alpha \beta}, \cdots$ diverge as $r \to 0$, but perhaps that is not enough. Intuitively, I expect the answer should be that $a(r)$ should be an odd function of $r$. This is because if we go to Cartesian coordinates and write $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, there would be residual square roots at some order in a small $r$-expansion, which presumably we could extract by taking derivatives of curvature tensors and building a curvature invariant that diverges as $r \to 0$. Furthermore, I think we must have $a'(0) = \pm 1$ to avoid a conical deficit (which, I think, would show up as a delta function singularity of $R$ at $r = 0$, and so is included in the above definition of regularity).

There is no choice of $a(r)$ that is ever going to make polar coordinates well-behaved at the origin. Polar coordinates are not injective at the origin, which prevent them from being a true coordinate system there, before one even gets around to defining a metric.

This is irrelevant, you can phrase the question as being about the limit r —> 0 without having to consider the origin itself.

In Section 1.3.4 of [1] Petersen translates the metric
$$
ds^2=dr^2+a^2(r)\,d\theta^2
$$
back into Cartesian coordinates which gives the components
\begin{align}
g_{xx}&=\left(1+\frac{\psi^2(r)-1 }{r^2}\right)y^2\,,\\[2mm]
g_{xy}=g_{yx}&=\frac{1-\psi^2(r) }{r^2}xy\,,\\[2mm]
g_{yy}&=\left(1+\frac{\psi^2(r)-1 }{r^2}\right)x^2\,
\end{align}
where
$$
\psi(r):=\frac{a(r)}r\,.
$$
The flat metric has $\psi(r)=1\,.$
The author then finds the following conditions for the Cartesian components of $g$
to be smooth at $r=0\,:$
$$\boxed{\phantom{\Big|}
a\text{ is smooth },\quad \psi(0)=1\,,\quad a(0)=0\,,\quad a'(0)=1\,,\quad a^{(n)}(0)=0\,\quad\text{ for every even }n\,.\quad}
$$
[1] P. Petersen, Riemannian Geometry.

Thank you, this is clearly very close to what I asked and to my conjectured answer, including the reasoning of Cartesian coordinates and the non-differentiability of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ at the origin. The step that is missing for me is what "smoothness" means, exactly. It should have a coordinate-independent meaning, along the lines of the curvature invariants being finite as I suggested. The current reasoning seems to rely on the infinite-differentiability of all the metric components when expressed in Cartesian coordinates. Can we phrase this in a coordinate-independent way?

The credit goes to P. Petersen, and to fellow MSE user @mollyerin who pointed this out to me in another context.  I have not given your further questions a lot of thoughts TBH. We start with a defective (because polar) coordinate system which we know has a regular metric once better coordinates are chosen (Cartesian). Then we tweak that polar metric and ask - hm - what question again? As far I understand so far: Petersen's exercise might be as good as it gets.

We ask that all coordinate-invariant linear combinations of covariant derivatives of the Riemann tensor are finite as $r \to 0$. I think I see how this connects to the Petersen condition. If we invert the metric you gave in Cartesian coordinates, one can check that under the Petersen conditions on $a(r)$, it is an analytic function of $r^2$ around $r^2 = 0$. Since the curvature invariants I mentioned are built out of derivatives of the metric and inverse metric, we know they are finite as $r \to 0$ from their expression in Cartesian coordinates, and thus in all coordinates.
